# What are some helpful chess tactics training websites?

Tags: tactics, recommendations

I like [Chesstempo](http://chesstempo.com/) and [chess.emrald.net](http://chess.emrald.net/)[1].

Are there any others?

**Edit (25.12.2020)**: Since at least 2018, [chess.emrald.net has often not been responsive](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/82oyig/is_chessemraldnet_gone_forever/).

Comment: Stack Exchange doesn't generally work well for questions that are just polling the community. The guidance is **"real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions."** That always sounds crazy to a new community, but trust me, avoiding these recommendation questions (especially early in the best) has proven itself time and time again as the core community starts to see where it all goes wrong. I urge you to read this short blog post: **[Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)** because I am running out of room here. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Chesstempo.com is the one I use. It's pretty excellent. I'd like to hear if there's a better one, though.

Answer (score 7):

http://www.chess.com/tactics/myhome.html

Free: 5 problems/day

Answer (score 3):

[Lichess.org](http://lichess.org/training/) has both tactics and opening training.

Answer (score 2):

[chessity.com](http://chessity.com) is fun, and the free membership offers 20 puzzles/day and access to multiplayer games.

Answer (score 2):

chess24.com 5 free problems a day.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://en.chessbase.com/post/chessbase-s-free-tactics-training).This chessbase site is pretty useful.