# What's the best chess tactics trainer on the web?

Tags: tactics

There are plenty of chess tactics trainers out there on the internet. What trainer works best for you? Why?

Comment: This kind of question is purely opinion-based, which [isn't a good fit for Stack Exchange](http://chess.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are some helpful chess tactics training websites?](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/99/what-are-some-helpful-chess-tactics-training-websites)

Answer (score 1):

chesstempo.com. 
free
tactics gets harder as your tactics rating increases
can play standard or blitz tactics (rating adjustment dependent on time took or independent)

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree that chesstempo.com seems to be one of the best, but I'd question how much use the basic (free) version is for improving your play. As the previous answer says, the problems get harder as you get them right which means you end up doing problems which are too hard for effective training. Also, you cannot choose themed problems.

The paid version, on the other hand, offers the possibility to build training sets based on quality, difficulty and theme. So, if you want a set of ~100 discovered attack problems which take you 30sec - 1min to solve you can easily request this, with the option of spaced repetition for failed problems.

Comment: Even with the free version, you can choose the Easy difficulty, which will serve you problems well below your rating.

Comment: To me, chesstempo seems more like a tester than a trainer. I'd like to see something with problem sets all based on the same theme, starting with easy and moving up in difficulty, so that you become trained in spotting that theme.  So you may enjoy the challenge but not improve your play.

Comment: The paid version also keeps an historic of your problems served, so you can easily, ie. retake the ones you failed.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Maybe you should have read the second paragraph of my answer before commenting?

Comment: Would be nice if the free version included a sample of what the paid version can do

Comment: Well, if you're not prepared to shell out a whole $4 for a month's membership to try it out you're probably not serious enough about your chess to need it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Chessity has been my favorite site for a couple of years now. At first I sort of dabbled with the free materials they offered, mostly theme based problems. About a year ago I read a book called "Peak" which opened my eyes to the realities of effective training, and eventually I became a premium member at Chessity. There are so many ways to train on their site, and they WILL take you out of your comfort zone, which is one of the prerequisites of effective training. I'm glad to say hard work and their well thought out training programs are really paying off, it's feels great to demolish people who used to give me problems. I love the site, though I don't always want to do the work. As Jan Gustaffson said, "Chess is a constant struggle between my desire not to lose and my desire not to think".

Answer (score 0):

I like chess.emrald.net/

because you really need to be fast to score points. this lets you improve blitz awareness a lot.

im 2100 fide. but on chess tactics i barely reach 1800

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

I use the chess tactics training site [Chessity](http://chessity.com) I tried many platforms, and each is good at something, but when it comes to fun, Chessity seems better. Wonder what others think.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Chess Gym](http://www.chessgym.net/flash/exercises.php)
I started this to get some end game help but they have a tactic trainer also

Answer (score 0):

[Chesscademy](http://www.chesscademy.com) is a cool new site. You can solve problems which gets harder as your tactics rating increases. There are also free courses you can take.

Answer (score 0):

Any tactics trainer will be better than none, and honestly I would not worry too much about finding the perfect solution for you. Most tactics trainers out there are pretty decent and should suit most people's needs. That being said I like the one of **lichess**, for the following reasons:

- gives you problems suited to your level (adapts to your tactics rating strength)
- takes the problems from real games, which potentially could be more messy/realistic than a composed/streamlined problem
- uses "spaced repetitions", i.e. if you fail to solve a puzzle, it will present you the same puzzle again after a while
- website works well (design/speed)

Perhaps other websites offer the same features, but since I also play games on lichess, using its tactics trainer makes most sense to me.